# Unital semiring of sets contains the empty set

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

In *A Course in Functional Analysis and Measure Theory*, Kadets gives the following definition:

> A family $\Phi$ of subsets of a set $\Omega$ is said to be a *unital semiring* if:
>
> 1. $\Omega\in\Phi$.
> 2. If $A,B\in\Phi$, then $A\cap B\in\Phi$.
> 3. For any set $A\in\Phi$, its complement $\Omega\setminus A$ can be written as the union of a finite number of pairwise disjoint elements of the family $\Phi$.

It is then claimed that the empty set is an element of each unital semiring $\Phi$. I'm curious why the following is not a counterexample.

Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty set and form $\Phi=\{\Omega\}$. Then $\Phi$ clearly satisfies the first and second axioms of a unital semiring; in addition, we have $\Omega\setminus\Omega=\varnothing$, which we can write as an *empty* union of pairwise disjoint elements of $\Phi$. Thus, $\Phi$ is a unital semiring which does not contain the empty set.

What's going on here? Is there an issue with my logic?

Comment: I believe you are correct and it is just an oversight from the author